# Returning jQuery dialog back to original state on close/save etc

Tags: jquery, dialog

I'm currently working on a jQuery Dialog feature where the open method is called through a inline Javascript onclick function e.g.

```
<a href="#" onclick="showDialog(this); return false;">Click Me</a>

function showDialog(entity) {

 //Set up some variables
 var id = $(entity).attr('id);

 //Create some Html form elements to go in the Dialog window
 var html = "<input type='text' name='name' id='' />" +
     "<input type='hidden' name='id' id='id' value=' + id + ' />";

 //Set the dialog HTML and trigger the dialog open method

}
```

This works fine, when I make changes to the content of the dialog, for example, hiding fields, changing content through Ajax calls etc and attempt to open another dialog after closing the other one, the changes are still present.

I thought of using the destroy functionality but I then get jQuery errors regarding the inability to initilise.

How can I return the Dialog back to its original state on close or save of the dialog?

Comment: Are you using the plugin given in http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by using a template div like this :-

Put the html you want the dialogue to appear everytime with (when clicked fresh or after a save or close) inside a template div like this:-

```
<a href="#" onclick="showDialog(this); return false;">Click Me</a>
<div id="dialogueTemplate">
  <input type='text' name='name' id='' />"
  <input type='hidden' name='id' id='id' />
</div>
```

In the javascript part -

```
function showDialog(entity) {

     //Set up some variables
     var id = $(entity).attr('id');

     //Then while displaying the dialogue, get the template
     var html = $("div#dialogueTemplate").attr('innerHTML');

    //fill into the dialogue's body
$("div#dialogue p").attr('innerHTML',html);

    //Apply runtime changes
    $("div#dialogue p input[name='id']").attr('id',id);

   //Finally display the dialogue
   $( "#dialogue" ).dialog('open');
}
```

Comment: Hi, this is what tried to do. Something must be wrong in my procedure because it seems to remember the previous state.

Comment: At the foot of my HTML template I have a template HTML block which is wrapped with (essentially) the dialog HTML. When the user clicks the on click, the js function sets some of the HTML. When the dialog opens, some more content is added/changed depending on the result.

Comment: @user275074 if you are following the above procedure, the content of the dialogue div should get back to the original state. Even the part of your code which you have shown, looks fine as you are preparing the html to put into the dialogue. But still if something is wrong, you need to debug step by step. Right after the step of filling html into the dialogue's body, alert `$("div#dialogue p").attr('innerHTML');` to see what actually is inside the body. Do the same after every step. Also check for any possibility of divs with the same id (`div#dialogue` or something else?)

Answer (score 0):

simply set your html variable to null in the start of the method

whenever you call this method ,it will be fresh...without any values.

```
var html= '' ;
```